# Visual basic application written for Jira and Excel file error message

Tags: excel, vb.net, jira

we have an Importer for Jira that imports projects and configures them. I did not write the code myself and there is absolutely no technical documentation regarding it.

A few days ago its started showing an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otzxN.png)

I checked the directory and the file permissions and everything but it is still not working. The other thing is that it is not working solely for one person. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
 Public Sub getValuesFromFile()

    ' if the property excelDefaultValues has already values in it break this sub
    If excelDefaultValues.Count > 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Definitions
    Dim ExcelFolder As String
    Dim selectedfile As String
    Dim excel As Application
    Dim workbook As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim column As Integer = 0
    Dim row As Integer = 0

    ' Define the location and name of the default values file
    ExcelFolder = "R:\PM\01_Team\01_Allgemein\07_Jira_Importer\Masterfile"
    selectedfile = ExcelFolder & "\" & "DefaultValues.xlsx"

    ' try to open excel and the file
    Try
        excel = New Application
        excel.DisplayAlerts = False
        excel.Workbooks.Open(selectedfile)
        workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook
        sheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)

        ' fails if the file does not exist, open a message box.
    Catch

        MsgBox("file template not found! please make sure that the file is in this directory:" & vbCrLf & selectedfile, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "warning!")

        Exit Sub

    End Try
```

Comment: My best guess would be the drive path is a different letter for that user? I've had plenty of issues in past with shared drives being mapped to different letters and causing some problems with file paths like this.

Comment: If that does end up being the issue, I suggest changing the file path string to the actual network location, not just the letter the drive is assigned.

Comment: Also is this written in VB.Net? `Try...Catch` aren't supported in VBA is all.

Comment: Already checked the drive, and it is the correct one. The interesting thing is that it worked well up until this week.

Comment: Naturally I'd have to ask, have there been any changes to that users machine or profile in any way? (I'm doubting this is the issue as *"I checked the directory and the file permissions and everything"*)

Comment: Your Catch message supposes a specific type of error - try editing that to show the *actual* error message generated when the code runs.

Comment: @TimWilliams could you help me with that? Since the code is not mine, I am a bit afraid to touch it.